# Parameter missing from body of curl request

Tags: curl, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I am having an issue trying to post some data to the Sharepoint API. I was able to do so in `postman` using the `form/x-www-form` bodies, but ultimately I am trying to use the api/requests inside of a webapp using a framework called Xojo.

Anyway, to do so I am trying to use `curl` and I get the response `request body must contain the parameter 'grant_type'` which is just a simple string with the name of the type. My curl request is as follows. Why would there be no data detected from the body? Any help greatly appreciated, I've not used curl much. Thanks!

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST                      \
  "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/tenant/tokens/OAuth/2?" \
  -d "{\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\",                         \
       \"client_id\":\"client@0tenant\",                              \
       \"client_secret\":\"client_secret\",                           \
       \"resource\":\"resource-string\"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your REST Api **does not support json requests** (check out [this page](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) about Oauth2). You should issue the following request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --request POST  \
  -d grant_type="client_credentials"                                      \
  -d client_id="client@0tenant"                                           \
  -d client_secret="client_secret"                                        \
  -d resource="resource-string"                                           \
  "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/tenant/tokens/OAuth/2?"
```

the `-d` option must be used on each key/value in your request.